# I am trying to get no of button clink in Label its work only 2 click

Tags: c#

```
int count = 1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {

        Label1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(count).ToString();
    }
}
protected void btncount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(count).ToString();
}
```

It works only 1 click after that it's not working.
What is the issue I am not getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Page_Load` method, this looks like a web application.  Web applications are *stateless*.  What this means for you is that every request back to the server will result in an entirely new instance of your class.  Which means this happens on every request:

```
int count = 1;
```

So by design in the code shown `count` *can never* be more than `2`.

You'll need to persist that value somewhere.  A database, a file, even session state could possibly work for your needs.  For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["count"] = 1;
        Label1.Text = Session["count"].ToString();
    }
}
protected void btncount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]);
    count++;
    Session["count"] = count;
    Label1.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

In this case the page creates an initial value for the first page load (in the `if (IsPostBack)` block) and both displays this value as well as persists the value in sessions tate.  Then the button click handler gets the value from session state, increments it, saves it back to session state as well as displays it.

Session state will temporarily follow that one user, but will not be permanent or visible to other users.  It's just a quick illustration of persisting a value outside the scope of just the page class.

If you want the value to be more permanent and global to all users, consider storing it in a database instead.  The overall structure would be the same... Create an initial value somewhere.  Then in the button click you'd fetch the persisted value, update it, and save it back.